# Parallelizing python code inside two nested functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing

I would like to parallelize some pieces of a code which has this form:

```
function1 (arg1.1, arg1.2):
    estimate some model and return it

function2 (arg2.1, arg2.2, arg2.3):
     prepare some stuff
     quality=[]
     for i in range(1,len(previously prepared stuff):
         model=function1(arg1.1=arg2.1, arg1.2=some_other_prepared_stuff_from_function2)
         q=calculate some quality criterion
         quality.append[q]
     return(quality)
```

Instead of the for loop, I would like to use parallelization, but I don't know how to do this because function1 is called within function2 and the for loop iterates over the length of an object which I prepare beforehand in function2. This "prepared stuff" cannot be parallelized.
The order in quality should be kept.
I'm working on a Linux Server and it would be helpful to set the number of cores which can be used.
I know the `multiprocessing` package, but I don't know how to use it on my code, as I'm rather a beginner in Python.
Some help would be great!

Comment: For how to distribute the loop, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52637805/9059420)